# If $a_n\rightarrow a$ then $|a_n|\rightarrow |a|$ why does it not work for series?

Tags: real-analysis, complex-numbers

Proof:

Let $\epsilon>0$ . If $a_n\rightarrow a$ there exists a $N$ such that for every $n>N$ we have $|a_n-a|<\epsilon$

For the same $n$ we have

$||a_n|-|a||\leq|a_n-a|<\epsilon$

Therefore $|a_n|\rightarrow |a|$

But if $s_n=\sum_{k=1}^n(-1)^kk^{-1}$  then $s_n\rightarrow \ln(2)$

But $|s_n|=\sum_{k=1}^nk^{-1}\not\rightarrow \ln(2)$

The textbook says that it works for

$\sum_n \overline {a_n}=\overline{\sum_n a_n}$

But why does not work this Argumentation for $|\cdot|$ ?

Comment: You still have that $\lvert\sum_{k=1}^na_n\rvert\rightarrow\lvert\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}a_n\rvert$, which is analogous to $\lvert a_n\rvert\rightarrow\lvert a\vert$ for sequences (applied to the sequence of partial sums). The difference with the complex conjugate is because you do *not* have $\sum_n\lvert a_n\rvert=\lvert\sum_na_n\rvert$ since, in general, $\lvert a+b\rvert\neq\lvert a\rvert+\lvert b\rvert$. A sufficient conditions for this to work is if $a_n\ge0$, but then the result isn't surprising either.

Comment: Because $a + b + c \ne \pm (|a|+|b|+|c|)$

Answer (score 3):

Your assertion that
$$|s_n|=\sum_{k=1}^nk^{-1}$$
is plain false. It it not true in general that
$$\left|\sum_{k=1}^n a_k\right| = \sum_{k=1}^n \left|a_k\right|$$